# How to add custom back office module in Prestashop version 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I'm new with `Prestashop`. I'm using Latest `version 1.7.2`

I'm planning to use `prestashop` as a `CMS` for my `mobile app`. I need to add some `custom modules` in `back office` for adding content into `Database`.

Existing Tutorials in `prestashop` are only for `1.6 version`. (Most options needed to install modules are not available in `1.7 version`)

Please suggest any tutorial for adding `back office module` in `1.7 version`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski sorry buddy. I'm looking for some support on 1.7 version and if you can suggest some edits to my question so that I can find better answers even that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you have to create your own module folder and put it in prestashop_installation_dir/modules.

A basic module is composed by several files,

1. config file XML (config.xml)
2. your module controller PHP (module_name.php)
3. smarty template file TPL (module_name.tpl)
4. logo (logo.png)

the question is too long to be explained here, but you can find all you need here.

[Creating a PrestaShop 1.7 Module](http://developers.prestashop.com/module/05-CreatingAPrestaShop17Module/)

Comment: I want a simple module having a form with image & text field and  should work like back office product or category module with option to open  fom from left menu.